# Cannot debug nor inspect external gems in RubyMine 4.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ide, rubymine

In an app using Devise, Rubymine cannot access source code of said gem with ctrl + B and underlines its methods saying "not found". Setting a breakpoint in a file opened manually doesn't stop the code flow either. gem is installed in "/home/arthur/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p358/gems/".

Is there any way too make RubyMine aware of this location and consider it part of the app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Overriding the controllers in app/controller/devise and specifying the new controllers to use in devise_for in `routes.rb` was how i solved this.